# NServiceBus in WebApp

Tags: c#, web-applications, nservicebus

I've tried to setup NServiceBus in a WebApp with the DataBus feature to no avail. This is what I have in terms of configuration of the bus,

```
_containerProvider.Register(Component.For<IProducer>()
    .UsingFactoryMethod(() => new NServiceBusProducer(() => Configure
        .WithWeb()
        .DefaultBuilder()
        //.AsMasterNode()
        .Log4Net()
        .MsmqTransport()
            .IsTransactional(false) // ??
            .PurgeOnStartup(false)
        .UnicastBus()
        .DefiningMessagesAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace == "Magma.CommunicationBus.Messages")
        .JsonSerializer()
        .FileShareDataBus(@"..\..\..\abc")
        //.CreateBus()
        //.Start()))
        .SendOnly()))
    .LifestyleSingleton());
```

I don't know if it's a permission problem when NServiceBus is creating the storage folder, but I can't even see that the DataBus is initializing. On the 'listening' side I can see this with this string in the output:

- File share data bus started. Location: ...

But I can't see this in the WebApp output. Also, when NServiceBus is initializing I can see (again in the output) a list of mutators that the bus is using. And again there is no trace of the 'DataBusMessageMutator'

FYI I'm using this to send email attachments. This is how I do this:

```
message.Attachements = new DataBusProperty<byte[]>(email.Attachments.Select(a =>
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        a.ContentStream.CopyTo(ms);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}).First());
```

I'm trying with only 1 but I'm planning to send a list of attachments.

I can't make this working on the 'sending' side. Of course it crashes in the 'listening' side somewhere in the NServiceBus code when the mutator tries to get the non-existing header to construct the file path of the 'thing' it will read. It crashes in the 'Get' method of the 'FileShareDataBus' class because the 'key' parameter is null in the 'Path.Combine' call.

What am I doing wrong or missing?

Comment: I was going with the 'trial-error' way of trying to make this thing work, and I don't know why, but by implemeting the 'ICommand' interface, it started to work. I may have forgotten to say that I was using the unobtrusive mode for my messages. People of NServiceBus, is there an incompatibility between the 2 features? (unobtrusive and databus)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I guess I found the answer. You seem to need to implement the I(Message|Command|Event) interface in order for the databus to work properly. Also, you can send list of items by using something like:

```
new DataBusProperty<IEnumerable<byte[]>>
```

I'm using this to send multiple attachments to an email message.

But I'm still curious as to why it didn't work with the unobtrusive mode. I hope that the NServiceBus people see this question and explain this.

Comment: The databus is not compatible with the unobtrusive mode yet since we need to replace the DatabusProperty with a convention to avoid requiring a reference to nservicebus

Comment: Yes, I saw that you seem to be trying to remove the IMessage dependency as much as possible. It seems to contradict the ICommand and IEvent interface as from what I can understand, they help the user tell NServiceBus what the message is about (well, a little). Will you add some sort of other conventions to replace those interfaces?

Also, thank you for confirming my thoughts on the issue I was having.

Comment: There is already conventions for doing that - https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/blob/develop/Samples/Unobtrusive/Server/EndpointConfig.cs